# Distance between two curves

Tags: python, gnuplot

I want to calculate the cumulative sum of the distance between two curves.

For example I have two files containing data, file1.txt :

```
# 
# IS_MassLossRate generated file
# 
#     wall_color: inlet1
# 
#     mp_mean:  mass loss rate (kg/m^2/s)  
#     mass_loss: mass loss (kg) 
#     total_mass: total mass of fuel (kg)
# 
#        time      mp_mean    mass_loss   total_mass
  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  1.50272E+00
  1.00000E+00  5.20347E-12  4.97380E-14  1.50272E+00
  2.00000E+00  6.28181E-12  1.06803E-13  1.50272E+00
  3.00000E+00  8.69515E-12  1.81632E-13  1.50272E+00
  4.00000E+00  1.35947E-11  2.92655E-13  1.50272E+00
  5.00000E+00  2.28162E-11  4.74731E-13  1.50272E+00
  6.00000E+00  3.91465E-11  7.85150E-13  1.50272E+00
  7.00000E+00  6.66501E-11  1.31650E-12  1.50272E+00
  8.00000E+00  1.11061E-10  2.21045E-12  1.50272E+00
  9.00000E+00  1.80245E-10  3.67706E-12  1.50272E+00
  1.00000E+01  2.84732E-10  6.01985E-12  1.50272E+00
  1.10000E+01  4.38328E-10  9.66449E-12  1.50272E+00
  1.20000E+01  6.58799E-10  1.51967E-11  1.50272E+00
  1.30000E+01  9.68644E-10  2.34042E-11  1.50272E+00
  1.40000E+01  1.39594E-09  3.53306E-11  1.50272E+00
  1.50000E+01  1.97525E-09  5.23350E-11  1.50272E+00
  1.60000E+01  2.74866E-09  7.61615E-11  1.50272E+00
  1.70000E+01  3.76683E-09  1.09023E-10  1.50272E+00
  1.80000E+01  5.09017E-09  1.53691E-10  1.50272E+00
  1.90000E+01  6.79006E-09  2.13599E-10  1.50272E+00
  2.00000E+01  8.95014E-09  2.92962E-10  1.50272E+00
```

and file2.txt which doesn't have the same structure as file1.txt but contains the same sort of data :

```
#temps  masse   Moy masse   MLR
11  1502.59 1502.6236363636 0.0063636364
12  1502.56 1502.6163636364 0.0072727273
13  1502.59 1502.6090909091 0.0072727273
14  1502.6  1502.6018181818 0.0072727273
15  1502.61 1502.5990909091 0.0027272727
16  1502.61 1502.6009090909 0.0018181818
17  1502.58 1502.6054545455 0.0045454545
18  1502.59 1502.6109090909 0.0054545455
19  1502.61 1502.6109090909 0
20  1502.63 1502.6072727273 0.0036363636
21  1502.64 1502.6054545455 0.0018181818
22  1502.64 1502.6081818182 0.0027272727
23  1502.62 1502.6118181818 0.0036363636
24  1502.59 1502.6145454546 0.0027272727
25  1502.56 1502.6181818182 0.0036363636
26  1502.59 1502.6181818182 0
27  1502.64 1502.6127272727 0.0054545455
28  1502.62 1502.6045454546 0.0081818182
29  1502.62 1502.6009090909 0.0036363636
30  1502.65 1502.6009090909 0
```

I want to calculate the sum of the absolute value of the difference between column 2 in file1.txt and column 4 in file2.txt with regard to the time.

I know gnuplot can do such things but I want to pass the value calculated (let's call it Diff) to a python script to do some work with...

How can I do ? Can I do this inside the python script and get Diff directly there ?

Thank you !

Comment: can you explain your distance definition more clearly?
is d = abs(f1_c2 - file2_c4)

Comment: @rabinutam d = Sum of abs(f1_c2(t) - f2_c4(t)) from t=11 to t=20 for example (The ranges of times (column 1 in the two files) are not the same !)

Comment: you need to first extract the data from these files. `numpy.loadtxt` would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, data_file):
        self.f = data_file
        self.read()
        self.data()

    def read(self):
        lines = open(self.f).readlines()
        lines = [_.strip() for _ in lines]
        self.lines = lines

    def data(self, comment='#', sep=None):
        data = []
        for line in self.lines:
            if not line.startswith(comment):
                line = line.split(sep)
                data.append(line)
        self.data = data

    def select_data(self, tstart, tstop, tcol, dcol):
        d0 = []
        for m in self.data:
            if float(m[tcol]) >= tstart and float(m[tcol]) <= tstop:
                d0.append(m[dcol])
        return d0


d1 = Data('f1.txt')
d2 = Data('f2.txt')
d1s = d1.select_data(11, 20, 0, 1) # 1 for col 2
d2s = d2.select_data(11, 20, 0, 3) # 3 for col 4

if len(d1s) <= len(d2s):
    n0 = len(d1s)
else:
    n0 = len(d2s)

diff = []
for i in xrange(n0):
    diff.append(abs(float(d1s[i]) - float(d2s[i])) )

sum = 0
for m in diff:
    sum += m

print sum
```

Comment: this is a basic solution
You can add checks, exceptions, functions for diff, sum etc